# How do I display content from a Url on my own page using jQuery,

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("button").click(function () {
        $.get("https://talaikis.com/quotes/", function (data, document, quotes) {
            $("#test").html(data);
        })
    })
})
```

It kind of works but ony the button from the url is displaying, the rest is not.

Comment: <div id="test"></div> is where i need to display the quotes

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use **[jQuery `.load()` method](http://api.jquery.com/load/)** in this case:

> Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.

Your code would be like this:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $( "#test" ).load("https://talaikis.com/quotes/");
})
```

**Note:**

The advantage of `.load()` is that you can load only a specific fragment from the page, you can check **[the docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments)** where it says:

> The `.load()` method, unlike `$.get()`, allows us to specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special syntax for the url parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It will display only the button and a text. Only that much in view is loading from server. rest of the part is output of the javascript execution. You can see a delay just before viewing the rest of content in that site. You are loading that section as html content and it will not work if you display the content so.